# Should naming an assertion affect the satisfiability of a check in Z3?

Tags: z3

We have encountered constraints for which Z3 returns `sat` but if we then add a certain named assertion then Z3 returns `unknown`. One example is:

```
  (declare-fun a () Real)
  (declare-fun b () Bool)
  (assert (and (<= 0.1 a) (<= a 10.0)))
  (assert (= b (= 1.0 (/ 1.0 a))))
  (check-sat)
```

Z3 reports that this is satisfiable as expected. We can additionally assert that `b` is either `true` or `false`, both of which are satisfiable as expected. However, if we use a named assertion for the value of `b` then the result of the satisfiability check can become `unknown` depending on the value. With the value `true`, Z3 still returns `sat`:

```
  (set-option :produce-unsat-cores true)
  (declare-fun a () Real)
  (declare-fun b () Bool)
  (assert (and (<= 0.1 a) (<= a 10.0)))
  (assert (= b (= 1.0 (/ 1.0 a))))
  (assert (! (= b true) :named c))
  (check-sat)
```

Using the value `false`, Z3 returns `unknown`:

```
  (set-option :produce-unsat-cores true)
  (declare-fun a () Real)
  (declare-fun b () Bool)
  (assert (and (<= 0.1 a) (<= a 10.0)))
  (assert (= b (= 1.0 (/ 1.0 a))))
  (assert (! (= b false) :named c))
  (check-sat)
```

Checking the reason for the `unknown` result (with `(get-info :reason-unknown)`) returns `(incomplete (theory arithmetic))`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that z3 is just picking the wrong tactic in the latter case. Replace your `check-sat` call with:

```
 (check-sat-using qfnra-nlsat)
```

And z3 says `sat` in both cases.

Why z3 ends up picking a different tactic is a difficult question to answer; I'd recommend filing this as a ticket at their github site; they might be missing a heuristic.

Side note: I found this by running both cases with `-v:10` and skimming through the verbose output. It's not a bad way to see what z3 is doing for short-enough benchmarks.